# Tensorflow - 'str' object has no attribute 'op' - Adam Optimizer - var_list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use Adam with var_list, but it is not working.

```
 def get_name_trainable_variables(self):
    var_names = []
    for var in tf.trainable_variables():

        var_names.append(var.name)

    return var_names
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in _get_processor(v)
    200     # True if and only if `v` was initialized eagerly.
    201     return _DenseResourceVariableProcessor(v)
--> 202   if v.op.type == "VarHandleOp":
    203     return _DenseResourceVariableProcessor(v)
    204   if isinstance(v, variables.Variable):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'op'
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you add all the code you are using? This method alone doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: what is the content of `tf` ?what does `tf.trainable_variables()` return ? We really need more here !